# Java EE - study material

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-7, java-ee-8

I want to learn Java EE, but I did not find good material to study. Could you recommend me some tutorials, or maybe some books that are easy to understand?

I need to learn especially Java EE 7. Thank you!

Comment: How do you define `good material`? There are plenty of resources if you do a quick google search

Comment: A material that is easy to understand...  more for beginners.

Comment: Is the documentation from Oracle not enough? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/firstcup/index.html

Comment: I've collected the resources I used to learn Java EE here: https://rieckpil.de/essential-java-jakarta-ee-developer-resources/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the official Oracle docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/index.html

javaranch.com when you come up with particular problems and are looking into solutions (Think there is a user there named Bear Bibeleaut who has many good 'opinions.').

Also find it helpful to read the Oracle certification guides, i.e. the SCEA Study Guide (you can get it on Kindle). There's a mix of theory, apis, best practices, and hands-on experience with learning J2EE. You can just download it of course, as you are learning.